# Derivative of $u(t):= \int_{t-\tau}^t f(s)ds \quad \text{for all } t \in[\tau,T].$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\tau, T$ be positive constants and $f:[-\tau,T] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ an Riemann integrable function. Define
$$u(t):= \int_{t-\tau}^t f(s)ds \quad \text{for all } t \in[\tau,T].$$

Is the function $u$ well defined? is it differentiable? What would be the derivative?

Since in the integral, I have $t -\tau$ instead of $0$, I am confused. Any ideas?

Comment: Write $\int_{t-\tau}^t = \int_0^t - \int_0^{t-\tau}$.

Comment: @ajr Thank you!